# Freeing allocated memory conditionally within a macro in C

Tags: c, memory-management, macros

I have a function that reads a csv file and then updates a `struct` with it's parameters.
I wanted to be able to cycle through a structs elements, so I turned to macros. The output of parsing the csv files is a 2 dimensional array of strings for rows and columns of the file. To convert the strings to their respective data type (currently the structs only have `int` and `char*`) I used a conversion macro within the macro used to cycle through the struct.

```
CVT_INT atoi(str)
CVT_STR str
```

However, when it comes to freeing the memory allocated by parsing the csv file, it gets tricky if in the file the strings are not grouped together at the start or end.

```
csv[row][col]
string|string|int|string|int
string|string|int|string|int
...

for(int row = 0; row < number_of_rows; row++)
    for(int col = 2; col < number_of_cols; col++)
        free(csv[row][col]) // frees string when row[i][3]
```

I could just make sure all the strings are at the beginning of the structure, but I want it to be dynamic and I don't want to have to think about making sure the data types are grouped.

I could free the allocated strings that were converted by CVT_INT, but freeing the strings used by CVT_STR would result in the struct's strings being freed. I could think of one workaround:
1. Allocate new space
2. Copy in the old string
3. Free the old string.

```
CVT_STR strcpy((char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(1+strlen(str))), str)
```

However, on implementing the above, it leads to a crash whenever it is called, and I don't understand why. Could anyone offer me an explanation and a way to solve it/a different route that does the same job? I'm aware it's not very efficient, so suggestions on improving that aspect are also welcome.

Another possibility, I could free only `int`. However, I couldn't work out how to do this in the macro, as it has to return an int.

Below is an example of me calling the cycle-through-struct macro, containing the conversion macro.

```
#define STRUCT(type, name, converter) \
        obj->struct.name = converter(csv[row][col++]);
STRUCT_FIELDS
#undef PLAYER
```

Thanks for any help

UPDATE:

Replacing

```
CVT_STR strcpy((char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(1+strlen(str))), str)
```

with

```
CVT_STR strdup(str)
```

worked, but I don't understand why. Perhaps someone could enlighten me?

Comment: Why are you using macros for this, and not inline functions [at least for the final step, you can still use macro to do the expansion of converter, but pass a function instead of a macro as the "converter". That way, you can debug the code (and it most likely isn't any less efficient, as the compiler will inline the function!)

Comment: Does your system lack `strdup()`?

Comment: @user315052: Since the comment on the existing answer says that the strcpy() doesn't work, I suspect that a function that does exactly that same thing [or do you think that `strdup` does something different from `strcpy(malloc(strlen(str)+1), str)` - sure, it does some checking if malloc is null, and such, but otherwise it's the same.

Comment: Thank you user315052, I have not seen that function before and it has solved the problem! From reading the man pages it seems to do exactly the same as I hard coded with `strcpy`, but for some reason it works where my code didn't. Maybe the macro didn't like the typecasting of `malloc`.

Inline functions - I am not familiar with them, but I was recommended to use macros to cycle through the `struct`. I am guessing that using the macro to to do this therefore dictates I can't use inline functions? I will look into this however, as the lack of debugging functionality is already frustrating.

Comment: I am guessing you did not `#include <stdlib.h>`, so your cast hid the missing prototype. With the missing prototype, and if `int` is smaller than a pointer, you `malloc()`s return value will get truncated, resulting in an invalid pointer.

Comment: `#include <stdlib.h>` was certainly there, wouldn't be able to do much without it!

Comment: It doesn't make ANY sense that `strdup` solves the problem! I will write an answer explaining how to use functions and macros...

Comment: @user2276412: Change the code back to using your `strcpy()`, remove the cast to `malloc()` and recompile with full warnings. Are you sure you are not ignoring warnings?

Comment: I get `warning: operation on 'col' may be undefined` during declaring the structs members, but I don't know if that's the cause:
    `#define STRUCT(type, name, converter) \
            obj->struct.name = converter(csv[row][col++]);
    STRUCT_FIELDS
    #undef PLAYER`

Comment: @user2276412: I need more info. Can you produce a small program (less than 50 lines of code) and the associated input that will reproduce the crash?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately not tonight though - sorry to keep you waiting but that will probably take me another hour that I'll have to do tomorrow. Thank you for your help so far though

Comment: The warning I was ignoring turned out to be the cause. For some reason, the macro doesn't like incrementing col within the array, causing undefined behaviour. However, if I simply add `col++;` to the line after it works. `strdup` has no apparent problem using the increment operation within the array, allowing a functional program that (I think) is bug free, nevertheless I have put `col++;` on a separate line now. I had written the small program but I don't think it's necessary I post it anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add one to `strlen` which does not included the trailing NUL byte.

```
CVT_STR strcpy((char*)malloc((sizeof(char) * strlen(str)) + 1), str)
```

or simply

```
CVT_STR strcpy((char*)malloc(strlen(str) + 1), str)
```

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is defined to be 1, no need to write it out.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work, the problem must lie somewhere else. Because it's in a macro, I can't use any debugging tools either.
I was taught that I should always use sizeof(char) because sometimes it is more than 1 (I think in some asian alphabets where they have a lot more symbols).

Answer (score 1):

So, we have a macro that converts things:

```
#define STRUCT(type, name, converter) \
    obj->type.name = converter(csv[row][col++]);    // Guessing `struct` meant `type`?
```

And it gets called with something like this:

```
STRUCT(foo, bar, CVT_STR)
```

Now, if CVT_STR is a macro, the macro gets expanded directly into the STRUCT macro expansion, like this:

```
obj->foo.bar = strdup(csv[row][col++]);
```

Now, if you wanted to step through this, you'd have a hard time, since it just does the macro as one step.

If instead, we write a function:

```
inline char *cvt_str(const char *str)
{
    char *tmp = strdup(str); 
    return tmp;
}
```

and use this function like this:

```
STRUCT(foo, bar, cvt_str)
```

now we can use the debugger to set a breakpoint in cvt_str, and step through it to see where it's going wrong.

Comment: Thank you, I will attempt this tomorrow, but I'm not sure it will comply with my other macro at first glance- I may need to replace that with an inline function too!

Comment: You don't HAVE to, as long as the macro exansion leads to valid C, you can do one as a macro and another as a function. But `inline int cvt_int(const char *str) { return atoi(str); }` should be about right.

Comment: I set the structs elements to this:
`#define STRUCT_FIELDS \
    STRUCT(char*, s1, cvt_string) \
    STRUCT(int, i1, cvt_integer)`

With inline functions:
`inline int cvt_integer(const char* str) {return atoi(str);}
inline char* cvt_string(const char* str) (return strdup(str);}`

And calling as before:
    `#define STRUCT(type, name, converter) \
            obj->struct.name = converter(csv[row][col++]);
    STRUCT_FIELDS
    #undef STRUCT`

But this won't even compile, saying there are multiple definitions of the inline functions.